# how to see if a certain value is in an array?

Tags: java, arrays, runtime-error

I am a beginer.

I tried to find if a certain value is in an array. i.e to see if mnth is in month1[].

Why is this code showing a runtime exception:

```
   ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.
```

How to avoid  this exception ?

how to  find if a certain value is in an array? with the for loop i tried to do that.

please tell me where i am wrong.

Thanks in advance.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

/* Name of the class has to be "Main" only if the class is public. */
class Ideone {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception {
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        String dt = scanner.nextLine();
        String[] date = new String[3];
        date = dt.split("/");
            System.out.println(date[0]);
            int yr = Integer.valueOf(date[0]);
        int mnth = Integer.valueOf(date[1]);
            int day = Integer.valueOf(date[2]);
            int[] month1 = { 1, 3, 5, 7, 8, 10, 12 };
            int i;
            boolean x=false;
        for (i = 0; mnth != month1[i]&&i<=2&&x==false; i++) {
            x = yr % 2 == 0 && mnth == 2 ? day <= 29: mnth == 2 ? day <= 28 : mnth == month[i] ? day <= 31 : day <= 30;
                }
        System.out.println("" + x);

    }
}
```

Comment: Which error ???? At tun time only exceptions are there. No Runtime error.

Comment: What is `for(i=0;mnth!=month1[i];i++){}`-the empty loop  doing there ? are you having `ArrayIndexOutOfBound` exception ?

Comment: @Sage yes. how to avoid it ? 
its not an empty loop anymore I changed it.. Please tell me where i am wrong ?

Answer (score 5):

1. Your indentation is very bad, improve it.
2. `date=dt.split("/");` - You assume there will be at least 3 strings in `date`, bad habit.
3. `for(i=0;mnth!=month1[i];i++){}` Will probably cause [`ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.html).
4. The line `Boolean x = ...` is very confusing, I suggest you to reconsider writing it. Also, why [`Boolean`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Boolean.html) and not the [primitive `boolean`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html)?